# On the generalization of polar coordinates for $n-$dimensions?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am acquainted with polar coordinates and their reason of being, that is: Taking a vector in $2-$dimensions, we can normalize it:

$$\cfrac{1}{|(x,y)|}(x,y)=(x',y')$$

And we can clearly see that:

$$(x,y)=|(x,y)|(x',y')$$

And we can choose suitable $x',y'$ such as $x'=\cos \theta, y'=\sin \theta$ because $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta=1$ and $|(x',y')|=1$. But how should we proceed for $(n>2)-$dimensions? For example, for $3-$dimensions, my guess is that it's a repetition of the previous argument, but now we must have $x'^2+y'^2+z'^2=1$.

My problem is:

- What will be the suitable functions for $x',y,'z'$ in terms of angles?
- What will be the suitable functions for $n-$dimensional polar coordinates?
- Can we find suitable functions such for some other parameter instead of angles?

I'm supposing that such generalization is possible, but I'm actually not sure it is. From the sources I've found, there is only for $2,3$ dimensions.

Comment: In 3D, there are 2 systems that could be thought of as generalizations of polar coordinates, namely, cylindrical coordinates, and spherical coordinates. I imagine both generalize easily to $n$ dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider case by case.

**Case: $n=2$**.

We have 
\begin{align}
x=&\ r\cos\theta, \\
y=&\ r\sin\theta
\end{align}

**Case: $n=3$**.

We have
\begin{align}
x=&\ r\cos\theta \sin\phi,\\
y=&\ r\sin\theta \sin\phi, \\
z=&\ r\cos\phi.
\end{align}

**Case: $n=4$**.

We have

\begin{align}
x_1=&\ r\cos\theta \sin\phi\ \sin \tau,\\
x_2=&\ r\sin\theta \sin\phi\ \sin\tau,\\
x_3=&\ r\cos\phi \sin\tau, \\
x_4=&\ r\cos\tau.
\end{align}

**Case: $n=5$**.

We have
\begin{align}
x_1=&\ r\cos\theta \sin\phi\ \sin \tau \sin \psi,\\
x_2=&\ r\sin\theta \sin\phi\ \sin \tau \sin \psi,\\
x_3=&\ r\cos\phi \sin\tau  \sin\psi, \\
x_4=&\ r\cos\tau \sin\psi.\\
x_5=&\ r\cos\psi
\end{align}

... I hope you see the pattern.

Edit: Just to be clear. For each of the above cases, I have provided **a** parametrization of the $n$-spheres which respect the underlying euclidean metric.

Comment: I suppose $\theta$ is the angle between $x,y$. What is $\phi$? The angle between $y,z$ or $x,z$?

Comment: Change that angle and see how the point moves.

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle between the $z$-axis and the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @JackyChong You make it sound like there's is a unique (or at least prevalent) choice of angles in each dimension $n$, which isn't necessarily the case. You may want to elaborate that point some more.

Comment: @dxiv I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: See for example the notes at [Spherical Coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) about ambiguities between the math and physics notations for $\theta$, $\phi$ azimuthal/polar angles.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle I don't know if I have answered your question.

Comment: @JackyChong It seems perfectly fine. Now I just need to put my had to work on it for a bit.